# Corrupted file after decrypt file using simplecrypt in python

Tags: python, encryption

I'm trying to **encrypt** and **decrypt** video using `simplecrypt` [simplecrypt](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/simple-crypt) and everthing works perfectlly but the problem is after program decrypt the video `Myvideo.mp4.enc` to `example-decrypt.mp4` the `example-decrypt.mp4` not working "Corrupted file"

My code:

```
from simplecrypt import encrypt, decrypt


def encrypt_file(file_name, key):
    with open(file_name, 'rb') as fo:
        plaintext = fo.read()
    enc = encrypt(key, plaintext)
    with open(file_name + ".enc", 'wb') as fo:
        fo.write(enc)


def decrypt_file(file_name, dec_file, key):
    with open(file_name, 'rb') as fo:
        ciphertext = fo.read()
    dec = decrypt(key, ciphertext)
    with open(dec_file, 'wb') as fo:
        fo.write(dec)

encrypt_file('Myvideo.mp4', 'xfxw3wxq233')
decrypt_file('Myvideo.mp4.enc', 'example-decrypt.mp4', 'xfxw3wxq233')
```

How i can fix this please.

Comment: What does example-decrypt.mp4 look like when you open it in a hex editor? Is it encrypted? Is just the end of the file corrupted? What happens if you use a key that is 16 bytes instead of 11? Just throwing some guesses out here. Also, I'm not a python programmer, but do `plaintext` and `ciphertext` immediately go out of scope after the `with` statements?

Comment: Try encrypting and decrypting without writing it out to a file. And try it with a simple text file before trying it with an mp4 file.

Comment: @MillieSmith It looks like `7363 0002 eae0 c78c b73c 19b0 c043 cc0e
71f6 9f00 a51b f27e 3d35 b978 c9f6 3540
ba62 0ee0 8150 501b ee46 afa8 0bbf fe8e
95fd 61fb 0ba6 e9a3 d9ee 9e34 0bbc 604c
ebde aa5a ` and i try with 16 bytes  key and the same problem.

Comment: @MillieSmith it works with string encryption but with files not working.

Comment: Do it with a textfile. Create a textfile with "magic coding" in it, then run encrypt file, then call decrypt_file and print out the plaintext instead of writing it to a file.

Comment: @MillieSmith Ok I try what you say and everything works well. it encrypts the text file then decrypt  it without any errors

Comment: What happens if you do the same thing but then write the unencrypted text file out to a file.

Comment: @MillieSmith With the same thing the encrypt and decrypt works good. When i try with PDF file it works but with video didn't works.

Comment: @MillieSmith Please did you know how i can use 'Cryptography' to encrypt and decrypt files like PDF file because i search a lot and i can't find one example about how i can use 'Cryptography' with files. I appreciate your help.

Comment: Do 'Myvideo.mp4.enc' and 'example-decrypt.mp4' still exist? Perhaps they're corrupted at this point and need to be deleted for it to work properly.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "use cryptography". The python library you're using above is using cryptography.

Comment: @MillieSmith The above library is 'simplecrypt'. I mean this one: https://cryptography.io/en/latest/